# Export content type: 'An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.'

Tags: nodes

I have a content type which uses a lot of conditional fields, along with an email field, field permissions. When I try to export the type, it produced the error 'An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.' and the export script seems to be truncated so the fields do not import correctly. 
Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a corrupted field. I deleted and re-added the field.

Comment: I have the same problem, now, how do you determine what field is corrupted?

Comment: you don't. You just have to try all of them.